# Выгрузка репозитория GIT на github.com с хостинга

Tags: git, github

Добрый день! Учусь пользоваться git при разработке проектов. Как говорит мануал есть 2 способа создания git репозитория.

1. Создать пустой репозиторий на github.com а затем выполнить команды:

   ```
   cd "папка на хостинге куда мы хотим разместить git репозиторий"
   git clone "адрес репозитория на github.com"
   ```

   С этим способом проблем нет, НО иногда нужно создать репозиторий с существующим исходным кодом. То есть жил себе код, и тут решили мы поработать над ним командой, надо бы его в git засунуть.
2. Проваливаемся в папку с кодом на хостинге и выполняем ряд команд:

   1. `git init` — инициализируем git репозиторий
   2. `git add .` — индексируем файлы в директории (точка отсчёта откуда git начнёт отслеживать изменения)
   3. `git commit -m "Комментарий к коммиту"` — Делаем коммит ранее собранных (проиндексированных) файлов
   4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ/НАЗВАНИЕ_ПРОЕКТА.git` — как я понял, создаём репозиторий на github.com
   5. `git push -u origin master` — ну и наконец отправляем наши файлы на github.com
3. Дальше система просит указать логин и пароль пользователя *[https://github.com/ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ](https://github.com/%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%AF_%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%97%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AF)*.

И мне выдалась такая ошибка:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
>
> https://github.com/maler1988/testgit.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

Перейдя по ссылке https://github.com/maler1988/testgit.git/info/refs нашёл [статью](https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days), которая говорит, что git перестал воспринимать подобные команды по протоколу HTTP (если я всё правильно понял конечно). На зарубежных форумах советуют использовать SSH, тогда создание удалённого репозитория будет выглядеть так:

```
git remote set-url origin  git@github.com:maler1988/testgit.git
```

но там не написано, как потом отослать в репозиторий файлы. Команда `git push` не работает, пишет ошибку и просит использовать для `git push` HTTPS ссылку на репозиторий:

> You can't push to git://github.com/maler1988/testgit.git
>
> Use https://github.com/maler1988/testgit.git

В общем я запутался в этом методе. Распутайте меня, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала создайте новый репозиторий на гитхаб. У вас откроется окно "Quick setup" на гитхаб. 
Вверху, под этой надписью, есть переключатель "HTTPS" и "SSH". Выберете "HTTPS".

Далее, если у вас уже есть локальный git репозиторий, и вы хотите его залить, выполните инструкции из раздела

> **…or push an existing repository from the command line**
>
> ```bsh
> git remote add origin https://github.com/ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ/ИМЯ_ПРОЕКТА.git
> git push -u origin master
> ```

Если у вас просто есть файлы, которые не были под Git, выполните инструкции из раздела

> **…or create a new repository on the command line**
>
> ```bsh
> echo "# ИМЯ_ПРОЕКТА" >> README.md
> git init
> git add README.md
> git commit -m "first commit"
> git remote add origin https://github.com/ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ/ИМЯ_ПРОЕКТА.git
> git push -u origin master
> ```

После чего обновите страницу на сайте, и там появится ваши файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно указали ссылку для ssh. Она, скорее всего, должна быть вида `git@github.com:maler1988/testgit.git`, а вы пользуетесь несуществующим протоколом git: `git://github.com/maler1988/testgit.git`